# Can I inform a remote host of the original datatype I'm sending in my byte[]?

Tags: java, casting, arrays, instance, instanceof

Suppose I want to create a generic container to send throughout a local topology of nodes:

```
public class StreamReceiver{
    byte[] payload;
}
```

On the receiving end, I want to be able to cast this `byte[]` to a specific datatype, likely passed along with the payload as part of the same object. So something like:

```
public class StreamPackage{
    byte[] payload;
    Object/String/Something: [some identifier of what payload type is]
}
```

So that I can check this variable on the receiving side to know how to properly cast the data?

Comment: Is possible for your `data` objects to implement [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)?

Comment: It is, but I want something that doesn't require constant checks of `if instanceof`

Comment: I'm not sure if `Class c = Class.forName(name:String)` and `c.cast(o:Object)` will do your job.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass("An object");
        StreamObject so = new StreamObject(myClass, "MyClass");

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(".test")));
        oos.writeObject(so);
        oos.close();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(".test")));
        so = (StreamObject) ois.readObject();
        Class clz = Class.forName(so.name);
        System.out.println(clz.getName());
        Object o = clz.cast(so.o);
        System.out.println(o.getClass());
    }
}

class StreamObject implements Serializable{
    public StreamObject(Serializable o, String name) {
        this.o = o;
        this.name = name;
    }

    Serializable o;
    String name;
}

class MyClass implements Serializable{
    String id;

    public MyClass(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

The output of this sample is

> MyClass
>   class MyClass

But it seams you must get the filed and method information only by reflection.

I can not think of any other ways.